# gsub! clean string, taking away apostrophe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, gsub, code-cleanup

Trying to remove the apostrophe within a string. Using the code below I've removed the apostrophe and the spaces, can anyone help me fix it so I'm just removing the apostrophe?

```
def clean_uniname(text)
 return text.gsub!(/\s|"|'/, '')
end
```

Comment: Apostrophe's and single quotes use the same symbol but have different meanings. Suppose your string were `"She said, 'I don't know'"`. Do you want to obtain `"She said, 'I dont know'"` (removing apostrophe's only) or `"She said, I dont know"` (removing the symbol `"'"`) or something else? If it's the former, it's a bit tricky because some words have an apostrophe after the last character ("bro'", or the possessive form for words ending with an "s", such as "Chris' car") and some words have multiple apostrophe's ("couldn't've").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\s` means "whitespace character", and `"` represents a quote. If you don't want those in your regular expression, pull them. For debugging help try [Rubular](http://rubular.com) for testing.

This means your code should be:

```
def clean_uniname(text)
  text.gsub!(/\s|"|'/, '')

  text
end
```

It's worth noting that `gsub!` returns `nil` if no changes have been made so an explicit return of `text` is required here if you're using the return value.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
    def clean_uniname(text)
     text.gsub!("'", '')
    end
```

Comment: tried it and i recieved this error:

testing.rb:41:in `block in process_unis': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: That error is not related to the issue you mentioned as you can see below:  2.2.1 :001 > string = "I'm a string"
 => "I'm a string" 
2.2.1 :002 > string.gsub!("'", '')
 => "Im a string" 
2.2.1 :003 > 
If you post more code I can help you with the other issue but you may be better off opening a new issue and marking my answer for this issue since my answer solves the question you asked.